# Datatables without gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

Is there any way to implement Datatables without using gem?. I was following railscast tutorial for Datatables, But then I realized there is no `application.css` file in the project that I am currently working on, but there is an `application.css.scss` file. 
So I created `application.css` and followed the procedure but It gave me some error... stating trying to over ride existing css setting.

How should I go about it ?

Answer (score 1):

The file named `application.css.scss` IS your application.css file. The extension(s), such as the `.scss`, ultimately refer to which rendering engine(s) the asset will be passed through. If you look at your browsers dev window, you should see a fully rendered application.css file.

In other words, when you put `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>` in your application.html.erb, Rails will render the file `application.css.scss` into `application.css`

To answer your question directly, you can use datatables without the gem like any other javascript library. Simply place the datatables library file in your assets javascript directory and include the reference in your javascript manifest (`//= require jquery.datatables`).